# Continuous maps and compact-open topology

Tags: general-topology, continuity

Let $X,Y,Z$ be three topology spaces. And let $f$ be a map from $X\times Y$ to Z.

I want to show that, $f$ is continuous if and only if $f(\cdot,)$ (as a map from $X$ to $C(Y,Z)$, which equipped with the compact-open topology) is continuous.

In fact I do not know is this true, but it is very likely. (At least with other very weak conditions, I guess?)

Comment: what do you mean by $C(Y,Z)$?

Comment: @StuKraji $C(Y,Z)$ means all the continuous maps from $Y$ to $Z$. And the compact-open topology on it is the topology generated by all $[K,U]$ (means the set of maps which map K into U), where K (resp. U) runs over all the compact (resp. open) set in the original topology.

Comment: In general this is not true. It is well known that the exponentiable objects in $Top$ are precisely the core compact spaces. If the spaces are Hausdorff then the expontiable topology in $C(X,Z)$ coincides with the compact-open topology. There some relevant references in nlab: https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/exponential+law+for+spaces , https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/compact-open+topology

Comment: Is this what you were looking for? should I add as an answer?

Comment: @StuKraji Yes, this is exactly what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general this is not true. It is well known that the exponentiable objects in $Top$ are precisely the core compact spaces. If the spaces are Hausdorff then the expontiable topology in $C(X,Z)$ coincides with the compact-open topology.

There are some relevant references in nlab:

- https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/exponential+law+for+spaces
- https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/compact-open+topology